# Is there a way to resolve assemblies outside of .NET code?

Tags: .net, installshield, gac

I have an installer that needs to verify the presence of certain assemblies in the GAC.  These are 3rd party DLLs out of my control.

Because it's in an installer, I'd rather not have this "checker" be written in .NET as I'm trying to avoid managed custom actions.  I'm thinking either InstallScript or raw Win32 APIs.

I'm aware of an approach that uses File IO functions to check for assemblies at various paths, but that seems somewhat fragile given policy files and the potential for redirecting assembly versions.

Is there a way to safely resolve assemblies outside of .NET code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Metadata Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233411.aspx) from unmanaged code. Take a look in particular at IMetaDataDispenser/IMetaDataDispenserEx and IMetaDataAssemblyImport.